# azurerm_storage_account module with optional for azure_files_authentication

Tags: azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure, optional-parameters, azure-rm, terraform-modules

I have this module written for the Azure storage account:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.ResourceGroupName
  location = var.RegionName
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  for_each            = var.storageAccounts
    name                     = lower(each.value.StorageAccountName)
    resource_group_name      = resource.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    location                 = resource.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    account_kind             = each.value.StorageAccountKind
    account_tier             = each.value.StorageAccountTier
    account_replication_type = each.value.StorageAccountReplicationType
    min_tls_version          = each.value.StorageAccountMinTLSVersion
    tags                     = each.value.tags
    azure_files_authentication {
      directory_type = var.storageAccounts.type
    }

  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_resource_group.rg
  ]
}
```

And I have this for my variables with the module part:

```
variable "ResourceGroupName" {}
variable "RegionName" {}
variable "storageAccounts" {
    type = map(object({
        StorageAccountName            = optional(string)
        StorageAccountTier            = optional(string)
        StorageAccountKind            = optional(string)
        StorageAccountReplicationType = optional(string)
        StorageAccountMinTLSVersion   = optional(string)
        tags                          = optional(map(string))
        azure_files_authentication    = optional(object({
            type       = optional(string)
    }))
    }))
}
```

And I have this as my block to add the Storage Accounts:

```
storageAccounts = {
    yyy= {
        StorageAccountName                  = "yyy"
        StorageAccountTier                  = "Premium"
        StorageAccountKind                  = "FileStorage"
        StorageAccountReplicationType       = "LRS"
        StorageAccountMinTLSVersion         = "TLS1_2"
        tags = {
            yyy= "yyy"
        }
        azure_files_authentication = {
            type   = "AD"
        }
    }
    xxx= {
        StorageAccountName                  = "xxx"
        StorageAccountTier                  = "Standard"
        StorageAccountKind                  = "StorageV2"
        StorageAccountReplicationType       = "LRS"
        StorageAccountMinTLSVersion         = "TLS1_2"
        tags = {
            xxx= "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, I need to pass azure_files_authentication as optional since the second storage account didn't use it, but I tried many different ways to reference that type variable with no luck.

For this one, my error is:

```
Error: Missing map element

  on ../../../../Modules/StorageAccounts/main.tf line 17, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage":
  17:       directory_type = var.storageAccounts.type
    ├────────────────
    │ var.storageAccounts is a map of an object with 2 elements

This map does not have an element with the key "type".
```

Can someone help me with how to work with this correctly?

Thanks in advance

I changed many times this module block:

```
    azure_files_authentication {
      directory_type = var.storageAccounts.type
    }
```

With no luck.

What I expected is to create one storage account with AD integration and one without it.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision the azurerm_storage_account module with optional for azure_files_authentication and one account with AD integration and one is without and I wa able to provision successfully.

Here to achieve this configuration I followed the structure so that configuration works fine as per the requirement.

**Structure:**

```
terraform_project/
|-- main.tf
|-- storage_accounts_module/
|   |-- main.tf
|   |-- variables.tf
```

Before executing the commands make sure you have **AzureADDomainServicesStatus** enabled for your tenant. So that you will be able to make the AD integration.

```
  Login Azure Portal --> Search for AzureADDomainServices --> If there fine, If not Create one
```

My Terraform code goes as mentioned.

**terraform_project/main.tf:**

```
module "storage_accounts" {
  source            = "./storage_accounts_module"
  ResourceGroupName = "demorgvksb"
  RegionName        = "east US"

  storageAccounts = {
    yyy = {
      StorageAccountName          = "vkvkyyy"
      StorageAccountTier          = "Premium"
      StorageAccountKind          = "FileStorage"
      StorageAccountReplicationType = "LRS"
      StorageAccountMinTLSVersion = "TLS1_2"
      tags = {
        yyy = "yyy"
      }
      azure_files_authentication = {
        type = "AD"
      }
    }
    xxx = {
      StorageAccountName          = "vkvkxxx"
      StorageAccountTier          = "Standard"
      StorageAccountKind          = "StorageV2"
      StorageAccountReplicationType = "LRS"
      StorageAccountMinTLSVersion = "TLS1_2"
      tags = {
        xxx = "xxx"
      }
    azure_files_authentication {
       type = "None"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**module configuration**

**terraform_project/storage_accounts_module/main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.ResourceGroupName
  location = var.RegionName
}

variable "storageAccounts" {
  description = "Map of storage accounts configuration"
  type        = map(object({
    StorageAccountName            = string
    StorageAccountTier            = string
    StorageAccountKind            = string
    StorageAccountReplicationType = string
    StorageAccountMinTLSVersion   = string
    tags                          = map(string)
    azure_files_authentication    = optional(object({
      type = string
    }))
  }))
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  for_each            = var.storageAccounts
  name                = lower(each.value.StorageAccountName)
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_kind        = each.value.StorageAccountKind
  account_tier        = each.value.StorageAccountTier
  account_replication_type = each.value.StorageAccountReplicationType
  min_tls_version          = each.value.StorageAccountMinTLSVersion
  tags                     = each.value.tags

    identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

}

resource "null_resource" "enable_ad_auth" {
  for_each = { for name, account in var.storageAccounts : name => account }

  triggers = {
    enable_ad_auth = can(each.value.azure_files_authentication)
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.storage]

}
```

**terraform_project/storage_accounts_module/variable.tf**:

```
variable "ResourceGroupName" {
  type = string
}

variable "RegionName" {
  type = string
}
```

**Output:**

**terraform_apply**:

[image]

Storage accounts provisioned:

[image]

[image]

[image]

ref1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-domain-services-enable?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_FileStorage&tabs=azure-portal

ref2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance

Comment: Hello Vinay, thanks for the help
I did the change you posted and now I'm seeeing this behavior for the existing storage account that uses AD:
- azure_files_authentication {
          - directory_type = "AD" -> null

And:
  # module.StorageAccount.null_resource.enable_ad_auth["xxx"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "enable_ad_auth" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "enable_ad_auth" = "true"
        }
    }

But this is being enabled for both, even the one that I didn't want to enable AD

Comment: Declare the authentication as none for the second storage account as both the 
azure_files_authentication type = "None" so that the second storage account will not be authenticated to AD which was happening by default.